# Anchor tag with jquery not working

Tags: jquery, html

Calling a jquery with dynamically generated anchor tag is not working. Whereas the same with hard coded anchor tag the jquery is working fine.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">      </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var value = "HI!!!";
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("#box").html("<a class='dynamic' href='#' dataid='"+value +"'>Generate</a>");
        });
        $(".hardcode").click(function () {
            alert("Calling function");
        });
        $(".dynamic").click(function () {
            alert("ggsss function");
        });

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="hardcode" href="#" dataid="sss">Generate</a>
    <button>Change content of all p elements</button>

    <div id="box">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Not working" is not a technical term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(document).on("click")` for dynamically generated element

```js
var value = "HI!!!";
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#box").html("<a class='dynamic' href='#' dataid='"+value +"'>Generate</a>");
});
$(document).on("click",".hardcode",function () {
 alert("Calling function");
});
$(document).on("click",".dynamic",function () {
 alert("ggsss function");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <a class="hardcode" href="#" dataid="sss">Generate</a>
     <button>Change content of all p elements</button>

     <div id="box">
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `dynamic` anchor tag class is added dynamically, you will need to use event delegation to register the event handler like:

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$('#box').on('click', '.dynamic', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("ggsss function"); 
});
```

This will attach your event to any anchors within the `#box` element, 
reducing the scope of having to check the whole `document` element tree and increasing efficiency.

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/fb1bha1u/)

More Info:

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/